# stages power meter, which crank arm do they use?

Tags: sram, power

stages claim that their product add only tiny bit of weight to stock crank arm (15g?)

I'm looking for sram compatible ones.

And I think sram eagle sx/nx/gx/xx1 crank arm has different weight.

So my question is, which crank arm (among the sx/nx/gx/xx1) do stages use for their power meter?
(https://powermetercity.com/product/stages-carbon-for-sram-bb30-power-meter/)

Comment: Single sided power meters from Stages are always on the non-drive side.

Comment: Looks to be X01 or XX1. GX carbon only came out recently.

Comment: The difference in weight on the non-drive side crank arm should be minimal, but if you want to be certain, send a message to the Stages support team - they are usually very responsive.